# How to create a session number from the ASPXAUTH cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I would like to make a human readable number from the cookie value to be used as a session number.
It should be unique relative to the user id.

I know how to retrieve the cookie, I would be interested in an algorithm to achieve this or maybe another idea to generate a session number?

What about:

```
String.Format("{0}{1}", userId, cookieValue.GetHashCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a SessionID in your controller using this:

```
Session.SessionID
```

It will contain the actual SessionID which will look like this: `q42eezgj3l5msxpwr5mbvhex`

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid(v=vs.110).aspx) it is stored in the cookie:

`The SessionID property is used to uniquely identify a browser with session data on the server. The SessionID value is randomly generated by ASP.NET and stored in a non-expiring session cookie in the browser. The SessionID value is then sent in a cookie with each request to the ASP.NET application.`

The `ASPXAUTH` cookie is used to determine if the user is logged in. If you need to decrypt it you should do the following:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];//.ASPXAUTH
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

Comment: @user2704 what do you mean by reliable? It is the actual session id, which is generated when a new session begins and is stored in the cookie I presume

Comment: The ASPXAUTH cookie is something else I presume.
Reliable, in other words the ASP does not internally mess with (ruin) it.
Oh and I have the session state disabled.

Comment: @user2704 it is used to determine if the user is authenticated and it doesn't relate to holding the sessionID at all